# I want to add 94 at the beginning of the very number i insert

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add 94 at the beginning of the very number I insert from this input area. This is POS system which is written under laravel framwork.

```html
 <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('mobile', __('contact.mobile') . ':*') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
                        </span>
                        {!! Form::text('mobile', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'placeholder' => __('contact.mobile')]); !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[screenshot of the area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBFas.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
 <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('mobile', __('contact.mobile') . ':*') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
                        </span>
                        {!! Form::text('mobile', '94', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'placeholder' => __('contact.mobile')]); !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

You should change second parameter 'null' to '94' of Form::text, it's a default value.

You can learn more from laravel's documentation :
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html

Comment: Thank you. It worked properly. But any way to Hard Code it as constant? Now it appear on the input area default, but also can edit or delete it. I want it to be constant. Any idea?

Comment: @Navod You should use javascript for that purpose.
For example:
`var input = document.querySelector( ".form-control" );
input.addEventListener( "keyup", handle);
input.addEventListener( "blur", handle);

function handle( event )
{
   var obj = event.currentTarget;
   var value = obj.getAttribute( "value" );
   if ( obj.value.indexOf( value )  != 0 )
   {
      event.preventDefault();
      obj.value = value;
   }
}`